# Why does JHipster project generation go to error

Tags: jhipster

I'm using

- jhipster 5.7.2
- node 10.15.0
- yarn 1.13.0

with macOS 10.14.2

After upgrading JHipster to latest version, project generation keeps failing:

```
? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Monolithic application (recommended for simple projects)
? What is the base name of your application? store
? What is your default Java package name? com.mycompany.store
? Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your application? No
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL)
? Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which *development* database would you like to use? H2 with disk-based persistence
? Do you want to use the Spring cache abstraction? Yes, with the Hazelcast implementation (distributed cache, for multiple nodes)
? Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? Yes
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Gradle
? Which other technologies would you like to use? WebSockets using Spring Websocket
? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? Angular
? Would you like to enable *SASS* stylesheet preprocessor? Yes
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? Yes
? Please choose the native language of the application English
? Please choose additional languages to install Swedish
? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use? Protractor
? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? No

Installing languages: en, sv

KeyStore 'src/main/resources/config/tls/keystore.p12' generated successfully.
```

events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:39:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1152:7)
    at getPath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/dir-glob/index.js:6:41)
    at globs.concat.map.x (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/dir-glob/index.js:47:59)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/dir-glob/index.js:47:33)
    at globDirs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/globby/index.js:58:9)
    at getPattern (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/globby/index.js:61:64)
    at globTasks.reduce (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/globby/index.js:107:19)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Immediate.setImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:427:22)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

I even tried running *jhipster* as a root (sudo), didn't make any difference.